# Query other attribute in MongoDB with DBRef

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, dbref

I have two tables' structure in mongodb:

**> db.mapping.find()**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d74f4941538c0b386090af"), 
  "tc" : DBRef("fttc", ObjectId("52d74f4841538c0b3860902e")), 
  "hit" : { "24" : 1, "25" : 1, "26" : 1, "27" : 2}}
...
```

**> db.fttc.find()**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d74f4841538c0b38609041"), 
  "full" : "build1111_tastcase_20", 
  "tags" : [  "tag_0" ] }
...
```

**> db.mapping.find()[0].tc.fetch().full**

```
build1111_tastcase_1
```

**> db.mapping.find({'tc.$id':ObjectId("52d74f4841538c0b3860902e")})**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d74f4941538c0b386090a0"), 
  "tc" : DBRef("fttc", ObjectId("52d74f4841538c0b3860902e")),
  "hit" : { "24" : 3, "25" : 3 } }
...
```

Now, I can get the items whose tc's attribute '**id**' is `ObjectId("52d74f4841538c0b3860902e")`.

But, how can I find **all** the items from **mapping**, whose tc's attribute '**full**' is '**build1111_tastcase_20**' ?

Is there any query statement ?

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Effectively what you are asking for is a join, which is not a supported server-side feature in MongoDB (by design).

Given that your `mapping` collection currently only has a DBref pointing to the `fttc` collection, you would have to solve this by using multiple queries and joining the results in your application. This would take three queries on the server side: one to find the `mapping` doc, one to find the related `fttc` doc, and then finally a search on `fttc` for matching documents with the same `full` attribute.

A better way to approach this in MongoDB would be to denormalise the `full` attribute that you want to query on, so it ends up saved in both collections.

Your mapping document would then look like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d74f4941538c0b386090a0"), 
  "tc" : DBRef("fttc", ObjectId("52d74f4841538c0b3860902e")),
  "full" : "build1111_tastcase_20",
  "hit" : { "24" : 3, "25" : 3 }
}
```

Your query to find the related `fttc` documents becomes a simple `find()`.  Since you are getting data from two collections, you still need to make two queries but this is one less query than the current approach:

```
doc = db.mapping.findOne({"_id" : ObjectId("52d74f4941538c0b386090a0")})
related = db.fttc.find({"full" : doc.full});
```

Answer (score 0):

you access 'full' by `db.dereference(db.mapping.find_one()['tc'])['full']`